# Packaging with CDBS: Unknown sequence cleanbuilddir

Tags: packaging, debian

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu package for testing, and stick to the rules given at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete.

As this is CMake build and I need to adapt the arguments to `cmake`, I'm using

```
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/class/cmake.mk
```

in `debian/rules`. Unfortunately, when I then call `debuild` I get the error message

```
$ debuild
[...]
dh cleanbuilddir
dh: Unknown sequence cleanbuilddir (choose from: binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep)
make: *** [cleanbuilddir] Error 255
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

Where is `cleanbuilddir` defined, or: Why does it fail here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake was, while the CDBS header `/usr/share/cdbs/1/class/cmake.mk` was included, the default target

```
%:
   dh $@
```

was still present in the file. Commenting out the later makes `debuild` run fine.